# An appropriate word for a mathematical object

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to call a mathematical object. This object is the intersection of infinitely many sets (indeed balls), to distinguish this object which is a set we need to give it a name. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Are you asking whether such a thing has a name, or asking for suggestions? If the latter, this is off-topic (naming items is [explicitly mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Naming%2C%20including%20naming%20programming%20variables%2Fclasses)); if the former, we're going to need a better definition, I think.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used. However, since this is appears to be about specific mathematical terminology, you might get better results on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KillingTime I think Mathematics will need a better definition. If it's provided here as requested, then the question can be migrated (rather than asking again) if it's better there than here.

Comment: I do not if there is already a name for this object or not. In mathematics, when we define a new object we give a name which appropriately describes the object.  Of course, it depends on the English knowledge, and not always mathematician can find an appropriate word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hull** is a term applied to similar spaces. As yours is the intersection of balls, it would also be a **convex hull** or even more specifically: a **Ball Hull**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257132211_Intersections_of_Balls_and_the_Ball_Hull_Mapping

Comment: Thank you, Ball hull is an appropriate word in my context.